# Combining two ecdf plots with different

Tags: r, ggplot2

At the moment I`m writing my bachelor thesis and all of my plots are created with ggplot2. Now I need a plot of two ecdfs but my problem is that the two dataframes have different lengths. But by adding values to equalize the length I would change the distribution, therefore my first thought isn't possible. But a ecdf plot with two different dataframes with a different length is forbidden.

```
daten <- peptidPSMotherExplained[peptidPSMotherExplained$V3!=-1,]
daten <- cbind ( daten , "scoreDistance"= daten$V2-daten$V3 )    
daten2 <- peptidPSMotherExplained2[peptidPSMotherExplained2$V3!=-1,]
daten2 <- cbind ( daten2 , "scoreDistance"= daten2$V2-daten2$V3 )
p <- ggplot(daten, aes(x = scoreDistance)) + stat_ecdf()
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x = daten2$lengthDistance))
p
```

with the normal plot function of R it is possible

```
plot(ecdf(daten$scoreDistance))
plot(ecdf(daten2$scoreDistance),add=TRUE)
```

but it looks different to all of my other plots and I dislike this.

Has anybody a solution for me?

Thank you,
Tobias

---

Example:

```
df <-data.frame(scoreDifference = rnorm(10,0,12))
df2 <- data.frame(scoreDifference = rnorm(5,-3,9)) 
plot(ecdf(df$scoreDifference))
plot(ecdf(df2$scoreDifference),add=TRUE)
```

So how can I achieve this kind of plot in ggplot?

Comment: there are several issues: 1) please provide a minimal reproducible example with data; 2) you shouldn't use `$` with ggplot2; 3) there's no reason to worry about having two layers with data of different length (but again, see 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, reshaping your data in the right way will probably make ggplot2 work for you:

```
df <-data.frame(scoreDiff1 = rnorm(10,0,12))
df2 <- data.frame(scoreDiff2 = rnorm(5,-3,9))
library('reshape2')
data <- merge(melt(df),melt(df2),all=TRUE)
```

Then, with `data` in the right shape, you can simply go on to plot the stuff with colour (or shape, or whatever you wish) to distinguish the two datasets:

```
p <- ggplot(daten, aes(x = value, colour = variable)) + stat_ecdf()
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what geom one should use for such plots, but for combining two datasets you can simply specify the data in a new layer,

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = scoreDifference)) + 
  stat_ecdf(geom = "point") + 
  stat_ecdf(data=df2, geom = "point")
```

Comment: Thank you - I changed the geom to smooth and now it looks fine. I have no clue why it doesn't work with my solution - but I`m fine :)